# Action to be triggered on Comment Approval

Tags: rules, comments, actions

How can add new rule to trigger when a comment approve, in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no rules condition to do this but there is a patch in the rules issue queue.
You can try using that, and if you do you can report back to that issue and help it get committed to the rules module.
http://drupal.org/node/1421058#comment-6532372

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way, You can use the hook [hook_comment_publish](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_publish/7) in your custom module.

```
hook_comment_publish($comment)
```

> The comment is being published by the moderator.

For eg:

```
function YOURMODULENAME_comment_publish($comment) {
   //your codes to do task
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can achieve with rules

[image]